# Ruby ActionMailer does not send

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

i am using the ActionMailer to send emails and internal SMTP does not require authentication. so my code is very simple:

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(
  :from => 'example@...',
  :to   => 'example@...',
  ...
);
```

but it doesn't actually send emails. do i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call 'deliver' on the mail.

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => 'sender@example.com', 
                        :to => 'receiver@example.com', 
                        :subject => 'An Email Subject', 
                        :body => 'Thank you for reading').deliver
```

Comment: hey Steve, i have another question. so am i able to use request.env in my mailer class? i got error that request is not defined.

Comment: @user1510412 Request isn't available in the mailer class (or so I've always understood). When I've needed it, I've used it in the controller action and passed it to the mailer class method as one of the arguments.